# Python script doesn't run on cmd when it runs on anaconda3

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, urllib

I have a simple python script that runs on anaconda3 shell but not on cmd.
C:\Users[username]\anaconda3 was added to the system Path variable and I have restarted the computer.  Typing python on cmd returns the same python version 3.7.6 as on anaconda.

a.py :

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://time.com'
pageHtml=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

**from anaconda3 shell**

python a.py

no error

**from cmd**

python a.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 3, in <module>
    pageHtml=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does Anaconda set ``PYTHON_PATH`` environment variable ?

Comment: anaconda doesn't add PYTHONPATH or PAYHON_PATH variables.
Added PYTHONPATH to system variable, doesn't help.  script still fails in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your python installation. Try uninstalling and reinstalling. [Link to Python Download](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-383/)

Comment: if there's a problem with the installation, why would the script run on anaconda3 shell???

Comment: Because Anaconda installs it's own version of Python,

Comment: Checked the anaconda3 navigator and installation seems fine. When I type python in cmd it points to the same version of python from anaconda3 except that the script gives me error